# Proof that if p: $\mathcal{P} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}$ is a monotonic function, than there exist a set $Z$ such that $P(Z) = Z$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, elementary-functions

I am attempting to learn set theory, but a specific lemma in my book is confusing me. It states

Let $p:  \mathcal{P} X \rightarrow \mathcal{P} X$ be a monotonic function on a set $X$ such that, $A \subseteq B \subseteq X$ implies $p(A) \subseteq p(B)$. Then there is a set $Z \subseteq X$ such that $p(Z) = Z$.

My book states the proof

$Z = \bigcup\{A \subseteq X: A \subseteq p(A)\}$ Take $z \in Z$. There is a set $A \subseteq X$ such that $z \in A$ and $A \subseteq p(A)$. So $z \in p(A)$. Moreover, $A \subseteq Z$, so $p(A) \subseteq p(Z)$. Thus $z \in p(Z)$.

I understand this so far, The union of all the subsets $A$ of $X$, which fufill $A \subseteq p(A)$ compose $Z$. Using the proof above, we prove that $Z$ is a subset of $p(Z)$ but this next part throws me for a loop.

By hypothesis, $p(Z) \subseteq p(p(Z))$. Therefore $p(Z)$ is one of the sets in the family whose union is $Z$. So that means $p(Z) \subseteq Z$. So we have $Z = p(Z)$.

Shouldn't $Z$ be one of the sets making up the union $Z$? As it fulfills the requirements. Additionally, how can we prove that $p(Z)$ is one of the sets, as we didn't prove, (and I don't know how to prove) that $p(Z) $ is a subset of $X$.

Apologies in my formatting/title is not correct, this is my first post to StackExchange.

Comment: It looks like $p$ is a function on $\mathcal PX,$ not on $X.$

Comment: The reason $p(Z) \subseteq X$ is simply that the codomain of the function $p$ is the powerset of $X$ - so any output of $p$ is a subset of $X$. Then indeed $p(Z)$ belongs to $\{A \subseteq X : A \subseteq p(A)\}$, because $p(Z) \subseteq p(p(Z))$, which follows from the monotonicity of $P$ and the earlier fact that $Z \subseteq p(Z)$. Now it follows that $p(Z) \subseteq Z$, by definition of $Z$ as the union over this set.